# The Initial and boundary conditions of a 2nd order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem

The problem is derived from:
[Original gradient index optics problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170142/how-to-calculate-desired-light-path-in-continuous-medium-with-gradient-refractio)

[image]

See the Figure above.

$O:(0,0)$ is the disk center of light source $\odot{O}$ with radius $3$.

Then the **profile** light rays of disk $O$ from the view point $B:(-14,0)$ is defined by segments $DB$ and $EB$ (also the tangent lines of $\odot{O}$ through $B$) when the refraction index is a constant value everywhere. -- By saying **profile** I mean, $D$ and $E$ are exactly on the edge of the visible disk.

Now if the refraction index is defined as:

$$n(x,y)=\dfrac{e^{\tfrac{(x+15)^2+y^2+12}{(x+15)^2+y^2+11}}}{e}$$

How to determine the two **profile** light curves of disk $O$ from the viewpoint $B$?

Per Fermat's principle, I tried to establish:

$$\delta\int{n(x,y)}\rm{d}s=0$$ 
and the second order nonlinear ODE via Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$y''(x)=\dfrac{2\left((x+15)y'(x)-y(x)\right)\left(y'(x)^2+1\right)}{\left(y(x)^2+x(x+30)+236\right)^2}$$

In order to obtain a numerical solution, it is easy to have one boundary value condition $y(-14)=0$ of the ordinary differential equation, but I don't know how to establish another, e.g, $y'(-14)=?$.

**Update**

I tried some calculation, and it seems, for any numerical solution $y(x)$, it will be difficult to determine whether it is tangent to the circle $O$ or not:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It sounds like your question is about setting up the additional constraints on the problem, which is more of a physics question than a mathematical question.